Hair from Sketchfab to Blender to Unreal 5.4
I am new to Blender and I am trying to make my own custom MetaHuman in Unreal.
I downloaded hair from Sketchfab, which I then imported into Blender and put on a MetaHuman head. Then I used the DAZHair converter to convert it to hair.
However, as a result I'mgetting this:

My hair was in multiple parts, so I combined them. I also tried the same procedure without combining the parts, but it gives the same result.


Why do you want to use hair particles? It looks like your model uses so-called hair cards that also game engines use for best performance. Hair curves and hair particles only work in Blender. To export them you need to convert them to a mesh. But this creates a lot of geometry and results in bad performance, especially when you animate it. So why don't you just keep the hair cards?

thank you so much for the help
